# Programming Languages that Make Use of Special Characters

Tags: unicode, programming-languages, special-characters

I'm working on a general-purpose programming language. In addition to the modern requirement of Unicode support in strings and identifiers, I'm considering supplying alternate spellings of some operators, specifically:

- Relational (`≤` `≥` `≠` for `<=` `>=` `!=`)
- Bitwise and Setwise (`∩` `∪` for `&` `|`)
- Logical (`∧` `∨` `¬` for `&&` `||` `!`)
- Arrows (`→` `⇒` for `->` `=>`)

I know that [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) and [Fortress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(programming_language)) make use of special characters—and the former is often the butt of jokes about it—but these are both very much geared toward academic and scientific use. Do special characters have any place in a modern, non-academic language?

Comment: It's not what you asked, but you could use ascii and then look at it in the [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) font. It uses font ligatures to transform groups of characters into other symbols. For example, if you type `!=` you see a (double width) `≠`.

Comment: Julia comes to mind. It has built-in aliases to some operators that use a Unicode character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Special characters have any place in a modern, non-academic language?

**Yes,** *but* because on most desktops the support for special characters is still *awful* (bad editors, bad fonts, you name it),

- You better be planning ten years ahead.
- You better be *very* sure there is a good, *usable* alternative using only ASCII characters.

I would never advocate a preprocessor: there is too much temptation and room for abuse, and unless it is done very carefully, a preprocessor makes it *much* harder to write good IDEs and static-analysis tools.

Some people like a *postprocessor*, i.e., a prettyprinter, that takes sequences of ASCII characters and renders them as something else.  While I have always found this style dreadfully confusing, it is quite popular and successful among some Haskell programmers.

Comment: Seem's like Donald Knuth's WEB & CWEB would be another example of postprocessing to produce special characters, wouldn't they? Of course, they do so much more than convert `<=` to `≤`.

Comment: I suppose if I wanted editor support done right, or done at all, I'd have to do it myself. My current thinking is that the "preprocessor" will operate strictly between alternate spellings, for presentation and inter-language purposes. The hope is that it could be used either forward or backward, and thus as either a preprocessor or a pretty-printer.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion they have no place in a language, but definitely belong in a *default* preprocessor.  You may get the APL-keyboard problem though. (and possible visual ambiguity).

A limited example of this as a pre/post processing would be cweaved code.

Comment: A preprocessor may be just the ticket, though I had been avoiding including one in favour of a more structured system based on templates.

Answer (score 3):

The special characters `←` and `⇒` are reserved words in Scala. `←` is used for introducing generator bindings whereas `⇒` is used in the function definitions to separate parameter lists from the function body.

**Examples:**

```
for {
  word ← List("Hello", "World")
  character ← word
} println(character)

val square = (x: Int) ⇒ x * x
```

It should be noted that Scala compiler also allows the ASCII alternatives of the above symbols (i.e. `<-` and `=>`).

Answer (score 3):

Isabelle (the theorem prover) allows LaTeX-style command sequences as valid inputs.  Various front-ends then do appropriate things to turn these into special characters.  The nice result of this is that it's still just vanilla ASCII text, but you can have all the nice pretty display characters looking as you expect in an editor that is aware of those characters.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting concept, but aren't you worried that multiple spellings of the same thing will make parsing the code more difficult, especially for IDE's? Not to mention the additional time taken to teach what those symbols mean to incoming new programmers? If you're supporting unicode and therefore possibly other languages (variables in japanese?), these make another layer of inscrutability. In addition, how useful have you found their logical opposite, the C trigraph ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C )? :-)

Comment: With my current set-up, adding alternate spellings for operators is trivial, and editors really only need to know that alternate spellings exist, not which are synonyms. I intend to support not only non-English variables, but *keywords* too (like ChinesePython). I haven't needed trigraphs at all, but nowadays a keyboard is almost guaranteed to have the characters needed for C. The single symbols are from maths and should be *easier* to remember. For example, it took me a while to break my dyslexic friend of his habit of writing `=<` instead of `<=` because of the symmetry with `>=`.

Comment: @Jon perhaps your friend is a Prolog programmer?

Comment: @Norman: Since I've seen everything he's written, and since none of it has been in anything other than Java, C++, or VHDL, somehow I have my doubts. But you never know what people get up to when nobody's looking.

Comment: @Jon: in-joke.  In Prolog, 'less than or equal' is spelled `=<` because they wanted to keep `<=` available to spell 'left arrow'.

Answer (score 2):

The one language I've used that relies on non-ASCII characters is [TI-BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TI-BASIC), which uses `→` for assignment, `≤`/`≠`/`≥` for comparison, has built-in constants `π` and `ℯ`, a `√` function, etc.

On the PC, I doubt that'd I'd use non-ASCII operators much, simply because it's so much quicker to type `!=` than it is to look up `≠` in character map.

Comment: Ah! I'd forgotten about that. The only reason they can get away with it is the specialised keyboard, combined with the fact that users accept that the typing speed is low on a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using the proper characters a lot. However, in order to use then I would really want a keyboard that had extra punctuation keys to be used for them. And while we're at it, things like `{ } ( ) " ? + *` should all be on their own keys too.

Comment: We need a programmers keyboard.

Comment: @GONeale: Hell yes. A while back, I gave up and changed my keyboard layout, swapping digits with symbols, and other common shift-symbols with their non-shift counterparts. It's made my coding worlds faster and more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a general purpose language, but these have a place in a DSL for a domain where they're sensible.  And it can certainly be done in some modern languages.  For an example in Scala, see [this blog post](http://gabrielsw.blogspot.com/2009/06/boolean-algebra-internal-dsl-in-scala.html).